# Where LINQ with multi inputs and multi fields

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have an API that contains a request param with List of an enum. Corresponding with each enum is each field on the table. You guy can take a look on this:

```
public enum Type {
   a,
   b,
   c
}
```

And in the entity I have this:

```
....
public boolean is_a {get; set;}
public boolean is_b {get; set;}
public boolean is_c {get; set;}
```

So my purpose is: when I submit the list of enum is [a,b], I can have a query that can check with Where method to find the record `is_a` = true or the record has `is_b`= true. 
One more thing, just one of three fields `is_a`, `is_b`,`is_c`.

**UPDATE**
Just for more detail. I give you guys my request param just like this:

```
public class RequestParam {
    public string id;
    public List<Type> types;
}
```

And I want to make a query with `types` in this params.

Comment: What would you feed into the LINQ, and what would be the result? This question is pretty vague and confusing as currently worded.

Comment: Consider using Flags for enum: [FlagsAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It would really be great if your code was in a compilable form that we could copy, paste & run.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to describe but I'm OK using LINQ with one field have many values like this

                `query = query.Where(e => searchParams.status.Contains(e.usr_status));`

But for many fields I cannot use way like that.

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy - It would also be great if you avoiding enums called `Type` and inventing types like `boolean`.

Comment: I don't know how to write that query string to that's why I'm here :D

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy What is `query`, `searchParams`, `status`, and `user_status`?

Comment: @Enigmativity It just an exemple. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Abion47: Just an example about Where method with one field, man. In my case it's multi field

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy - You don't need to write the code for the query - you just need to write all of the rest of the code so that we can then just write the query. You should make our job easy.

Comment: Please take a look on my new update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a time to research, I find out we can use Linqkit to build a dynamic query:

```
var searchQuery = PredicateBuilder.New<YourModel>();

  foreach (Type item in searchParams.types)
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case Type.a:
                        searchQuery = searchQuery.Or(e => e.is_a);
                        //query = query.Where(e => e.is_pro);
                        break;
                    case Type.b:
                        searchQuery = searchQuery.Or(e => e.is_b);
                        break;
                    case Type.c:
                        searchQuery = searchQuery.Or(e => e.is_c);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            query = query.AsExpandable().Where(searchQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

If I assume that your entity type is called `Entity` and that you have a list of `entities` that you are trying to query, then this works for me:

```
var check = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Entity, bool>>()
{
    { Type.a, entity => entity.is_a },
    { Type.b, entity => entity.is_b },
    { Type.c, entity => entity.is_c },
};

var entities = new List<Entity>(); /* populated somehow */

var types = new [] { Type.a, Type.b };

var query =
    from entity in entities
    where types.Any(type => check[type](entity))
    /* use `.All` if you want all props to be true */
    select entity;
```

Comment: I suppose OP want `types.Any`

Comment: I think your answer is really near what I want but could you take a look at my new update? I don't use `Dictionary` like that, just a `List`

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy - The dictionary is part of my solution - it's needed to query your list.

Comment: @Enigmativity `var entities = new List<Entity>();` in my code it's not list of entity.. It's a `IQueryable`. How can I apply it ?

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy - Not, if it's from a database. Try `Dictionary<Type, Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>` and see if that works. Otherwise you might have to bring partial results into memory first.

Answer (score 1):

Use right tool for the job.

Instead of wasting memory with collection of enums(type Integer) use only one integer for saving more then one enum value. Define your enum with `FlagsAttrbute` and set values of enum to be power of two.

```
[FlagsAttribute] 
public enum MyType 
{
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 4,
    d = 8
}

public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public MyType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add values of the `MyType` enum

```
var typeItem = new Item();   
typeItem.Type |= MyType.c;
typeItem.Type |= MyType.d;
```

And use `.HasFlag()` method to check if value contain particular enum value

```
var selected = items.Where(item => item.Type.HasFlag(MyType.a) ||
                                   item.Type.HasFlag(MyType.b) ||
                                   item.Type.HasFlag(MyType.c));
// use selected values
```

Or use bitwise operator `&` for comparing in more effective way

```
MyType requiredTypes = MyType.a | MyType.b | MyType.c; // as integer it equals 7

var items = new[]
{
    new Item { Id = "1", Type = MyType.a | MyType.b},
    new Item { Id = "2", Type = MyType.a | MyType.b | MyType.c},
    new Item { Id = "3", Type = MyType.a},
    new Item { Id = "4", Type = MyType.d}       
}
const int REQUIRED_TYPES = 7;
var selected = items.Where(item => ((int)item.Type & REQUIRED_TYPES) > 0);
// will return items with Ids
// 1, 2, 3
```

Then instead of three boolean properties you can use one

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public MyType Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            const int REQUIRED_TYPES = 7;
            var result = (int)item.Type & REQUIRED_TYPES;
            return result > 0;
        }
    }

    // You can make adding types in more readable way
    public void AddType(MyType type)
    {
        Type |= type;
    }
}
```

You can still use `.HasFlag` method to check if some particular flag is set

```
var item = new Item();
item.AddType(MyType.c);

if (item.Type.HasFlag(MyType.c))
{

}
```